# Maintaining a reference inside a Task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I've put together a simple demo class that looks like this:

```
    public class HelloWorld
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public Main()
    {
        var h = new HelloWorld() { Name = "A" };
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Console.WriteLine(h.Name); });
        h = new HelloWorld() { Name = "B" };
    }
```

The following code prints:

> B

Which is perfectly logical, but not what I want (I want to print `A`).
I would expect to be able to call `StartNew()` with an argument, which would preserve the first reference to `h` inside the delegate, but I can't see this option.

Am I missing something?

Edit: I can see that I can use

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action<object>((obj) => { Console.WriteLine((obj as Hello).Name); }),h);
```

Being forced to pass in a type of `object` seems a bit .NET 1.1 / pre-generics to me though, so hoping for a better option.

Comment: On a side note, you shouldn't be using `StartNew`. Use `Task.Run` instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you've encountered is called a *closure* and it's not unique to tasks. Every time you use a variable in a **lambda**, it gets captured by the compiler in a special class it builds just for this purpose. The compiler generates roughly something like:

```
public void Main()
{
    var closure = new Main_Closure();
    closure.h = new HelloWorld() { Name = "A" };
    Task.Factory.StartNew(closure.M1);
    closure.h = new HelloWorld() { Name = "B" };
}

class Main_Closure
{
    public HelloWorld h;

    public void M1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(h.Name); 
    }
}
```

And since `closure.h` could be assigned again before the task starts, you get the result you're seeing.

In this case, you can simply use another variable to store your new object. Or use another variable just before invoking the lambda, e.g.

```
var h1 = h;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Console.WriteLine(h1.Name); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap task creation in a method to prevent closure.

```
static Task DoAsync<T>(Action<T> action, T arg)
{
    return Task.Run(() => action(arg));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action<HelloWorld> hello = (HelloWorld h2) => { Console.WriteLine(h2.Name); };

    var h = new HelloWorld() { Name = "A" };
    Task task = DoAsync(hello, h);
    var h = new HelloWorld() { Name = "B" };
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What you are experiencing is a very powerful mechanism called a closure. Its extremely useful in a miriad of circumstances. Take a more in depth on how closures work at: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx

The problem in your case is that h changes before the Task had a chance to run. Notice that this is mere luck, some time the task might run first some others it might not.

One thing you could possibly do in your case to fix this is to simply **await** the Task.

If your code is on a main method you can achieve this by simply adding .Wait() at the end of your line:

```
var h = new HelloWorld() { Name = "A" };
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Console.WriteLine(h.Name); }).Wait();
h = new HelloWorld() { Name = "B" };
```

If you are on any other method you can simply await the task with the await keyword and making the method async:

```
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    var h = new HelloWorld() { Name = "A" };
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Console.WriteLine(h.Name); });
    h = new HelloWorld() { Name = "B" };
}
```

Also bear in mind that using Task.Factory.StartNew is not the best option in most circumstances. Try to favour the use of Task.Run instead.

Comment: @EliArbel is right. Imagine if I changed the declaration of `h` to outside the scope of the method body - you still couldn't be sure that by the time the closure executed it would have the same reference regardless of `await` or not.

Comment: @EliArbel, of course it does, .Wait() will lock until the task is completed and await creates a continuation.

Comment: @maxp, I wrongly assumed, as per your example, that you simply wanted to execute things in a certain order and hence why blocking the execution would have solved your issue. My bad, although you might still want to consider using Task.Run instead.

Comment: Sadly my reputation is not high enough to comment on other peoples posts, bear in mind that while making a copy of a variable is one of the usual ways of dealing with closures, as @EliArbel correctly states, if the variable is of a reference type, this wont protect you if what changes is something inside the variable and not the reference itself. Meaning, if instead of doing **h = new HelloWorld();** you did **h.Name = "B"** the task would probably still print "B" when executed!